# How to add copyright text automatically to C++ source and header files in Visual Studio 2019 Professional?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, copyright-display

Here is the problem:
I have a root folder with sub folders containing all my structured code / 3rd party libraries / external dependencies. Now previously I used to develop with VSCode and used the Copyrighter extension by FordLabs to automatically insert the copyright text into all new files, which looked like this:

```
/*
 *   Copyright (c) 2023 My Company Name
 *   All rights reserved.
 */
```

My question is, how can I do the same for Visual Studio? Does there exist a plugin/extension that helps me do it?

Comment: I use to maintain my copyright notices with mere "replace in files". You can also define code snippets for single-key insertion.

Comment: @YvesDaoust can you please give some more details? How do you define code snippets?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?source=recommendations&view=vs-2022

Comment: What I do is just use a "magic" comment in my source files (like `// [copyright here]`) and then I have a `git` pre-commit hook that is a small python script that scans all the 'about to be comitted' files for that magic string and replaces it with the proper copyright notice before committing. Works well enough.

Comment: Did the extension for VS2019 work for you? Are there any new errors? You can find historical versions in the product overview.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the extension [License Header Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StefanWenig.LicenseHeaderManager) for VS2019

Support for Visual Studio 2019 + 2017 is provided via separate package available on GitHub as [LicenseHeaderManager.2019.vsix](https://github.com/rubicon-oss/LicenseHeaderManager/releases/download/5.0.1/LicenseHeaderManager.2019.vsix)

Comment: I tried installing this and apparently it is only supported upto VS 2018. Here is the [install log](https://pastebin.com/raw/wt5yhEeM)

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide the direct link for the VS2019 VSIX installer. (The log you provided shows that you tried to use the VS2022 VSIX installer)